# Better way to assign value out from multiple result if the value is not null?

Tags: c#, if-statement, null

This may sound simple, but i really want to find a better way of writing the below code,

```
        if (Master.SerialNo1 != null)
        {
            result.ChipId = Master.SerialNo1;
        }
        if (Master.SerialNo2 != null)
        {
            result.ChipId = Master.SerialNo2;
        }
        if (Master.SerialNo3 != null)
        {
            result.ChipId = Master.SerialNo3;
        }
        if (Master.SerialNo4 != null)
        {
            result.ChipId = Master.SerialNo4;
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs [CodeReview.SE]

Comment: The only alternative i see is `result.ChipId = Master.SerialNoX != null ? Master.SerialNoX : [...]` but it does exaclty the same, just in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `??` operator:

```
result.ChipId = Master.SerialNo1 ?? Master.SerialNo2 ?? Master.SerialNo3 ?? Master.SerialNo4 ?? null;
```

Of course, instead of `null` you can use any default value.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the types of ChipId and SerialNo are the same, how about:

```
result.ChipId = Master.SerialNo1 ?? Master.SerialNo2 ?? Master.SerialNo3 ?? Master.SerialNo4;
```

This will assign to ChipId the first non-null reference in the order they occur on the right hand side.

This might be more readable formatted over multiple lines:

```
result.ChipId = 
       Master.SerialNo1 
    ?? Master.SerialNo2 
    ?? Master.SerialNo3 
    ?? Master.SerialNo4;
```

`??` is known as the ["null coalescing operator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173224.aspx).